# Find all C.id where none of the rows of B have is_true='Y'?

Tags: mysql, loop

There are two tables C and B.

They're connected by `C.id=B.cid`.

I need to find all the `C.id` es where:

- None of the rows corresponding to `cid` has `is_true='Y'`

I've tried various queries but can't wrap my head around any of them. This is one of my ideas.

```
select * from 
C inner join B 
on C.id=B.cid 
where
-- loop all rows of B using B.cid 
-- output if the row has is_true!='Y'
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is I've to obfuscate the data else I'm gonna get fired. obfuscating is insanely time consuming. I'm working on it.

Comment: Why not encrypt it

Comment: "*obfuscating is insanely time consuming.*" - You've already provided an example query for 2 imaginary tables. It shouldn't take anyone more than 15 minutes to provide a couple of made up rows with different example data that would fit a couple of different scenarios in your case. Otherwise, as you can see, it's hard for someone to give you a meaningful answer.

Comment: Ok data is ready. I'm looking how to create a table.

Comment: Put the data above. Please check. @J.D.

Comment: @barnyard9 Thanks, that helps. Please see my simple answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT c.id
FROM c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM b
    WHERE b.cid = c.id
      AND is_true='Y'
    )
```

| id |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NUkBxNWY)

Comment: I verified for few datas, and it's not working as expected? This is giving 0 rows for in B table for cid.

Comment: Provide a sample according to [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3. The sample data must contain all possible variations.

Comment: put the data above

Answer (score 0):

Since all you're looking for is the key field, `C.id` aka `B.cid`, then you can accomplish your goal simply with a [`GROUP BY` clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) like so:

```
SELECT cid
FROM B
GROUP BY cid
HAVING MAX(is_true) = 'N'
```

Simplified example [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RXs_bc0n) to demonstrate.

Comment: Maybe `MAX(is_true) = 'N'` is enough?

Comment: @Akina Yes, you're right. Thanks!